# How can I join users and roles with Knex?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to join my users and roles tables. Users table has a `role_id` that references role id.

When I try to join, I get an error:

```js
function getAll() {
  return db('users')
    .select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'active', 'profile_photo', 'role_id')
    .leftJoin('roles', 'roles.id', 'users.role_id')
    .orderBy('id')
}
```

```
(node:66281) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: select "id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "active", "profile_photo", "role_id" from "users" left join "roles" on "roles"."id" = "users"."role_id" order by "id" asc - column reference "id" is ambiguous
```

Comment: Well column reference "id" is ambiguous. You have to specify which id you would like to use. For example `users.id`.

Comment: Thank you @Jax-p, to clarify, just needed the .select('id') -> .select('users.id')

Comment: @Jax-p, answers go down there. You short-circuit the process when you post them as comments.